# How to save a string as float or integer in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoalchemy

I have a text file containing these line for example

```
2017-03-14 10:33:56.661 +0800, Number of child: 898
2017-03-14 10:33:56.661 +0800, Volume of water: 86.75
2017-03-14 10:33:56.661 +0800, Size of field: 99.58
2017-03-14 10:34:01.672 +0800, Number of Dog: 779
2017-03-14 10:34:01.672 +0800, Number of child: 898
2017-03-14 10:34:01.672 +0800, Volume of water: 86.75
2017-03-14 10:34:01.672 +0800, Size of field: 99.58
2017-03-14 10:34:06.677 +0800, Number of Dog: 789
....
....
```

I want to store this data in using mongodb and mongoalchemy. I want it to look like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58d8e7e2a0bae63d30e8601a"),
"Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-14T10:33:56.661Z"),
"Data": "Number of child"
"Value" : 898,
"Timezone" : "+0800"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58d8e7e2a0bae63d30e8601a"),
"Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-14T10:33:56.661Z"),
"Data": "Volume of water"
"Value" : 86.75,
"Timezone" : "+0800"
}
{...
....
....
}
```

My code so far

`model.py`

```
from mongoalchemy.document import Document
from mongoalchemy.fields import *

class the_data(Document):
    Timestamp = DateTimeField()
    Timezone = StringField()
    Data = StringField()
    Value = FloatField()
```

`savetodb.py`

```
from mongoalchemy.session import Session
from model import text_data, html_data
import datetime
import os

path = "all_files/"

def save_to_db():
    dir_path = os.listdir(path)
    session = Session.connect('mockdb')  # mongodb's database name
    session.clear_collection(the_data)
    for file in dir_path:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            f = open(path + file, "r")
            for line in f:
                word = ["Number of child", "Number of Dog ", "Volume of Water", "Size of field"]
                if word[0] in line:
                    timestamp = line[0:23].strip()
                    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                    tzone = [i for i in line.split() if i.startswith("+")]
                    timezone = ''.join(tzone)
                    data_child = line.split(": ", 1)[0]
                    num_child = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
                    numchild = float(num_child)
                    data_save = the_data(Timestamp=t,
                                          Timezone=timezone,
                                          Data=data_child,
                                          Value=numchild)
                    session.save(data_save)

                elif word[1] in line:
                    timestamp = line[0:23].strip()
                    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                    tzone = [i for i in line.split() if i.startswith("+")]
                    timezone = ''.join(tzone)
                    data_dog = line.split(": ", 1)[0]
                    num_dog = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
                    numdog = float(num_child)
                    data_save = the_data(Timestamp=t,
                                          Timezone=timezone,
                                          Data=data_dog,
                                          Value=numdog)
                    session.save(data_save)                        

                elif word[2] in line:
                    timestamp = line[0:23].strip()
                    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                    tzone = [i for i in line.split() if i.startswith("+")]
                    timezone = ''.join(tzone)
                    data_water = line.split(": ", 1)[0]
                    vol_water = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
                    volwater = float(num_child)
                    data_save = the_data(Timestamp=t,
                                          Timezone=timezone,
                                          Data=data_water,
                                          Value=volwater)
                    session.save(data_save)

                elif word[3] in line:
                    timestamp = line[0:23].strip()
                    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                    tzone = [i for i in line.split() if i.startswith("+")]
                    timezone = ''.join(tzone)
                    data_field = line.split(": ", 1)[0]
                    size_field = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
                    sizefield = float(num_child)
                    data_save = the_data(Timestamp=t,
                                          Timezone=timezone,
                                          Data=data_field,
                                          Value=savefield)
                    session.save(data_save)



save_to_db()
```

I keep the text file under subfolder named `all_files`

I run above script and here is what I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 88, in <module>
save_to_db()
  File "tasks.py", line 38, in save_to_db
Value=numchild)
  File "/Users/Fang/workspace/test_celery3/celery3-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoalchemy/document.py", line 230, in __init__
raise ExtraValueException(k)
mongoalchemy.exceptions.ExtraValueException: Data
```

What is the meaning of the error? Did I miss something in the script? While at it, am I going on the right direction to properly store the data in the database?

Additional information : There is even no database `mockdb` after I run the script.

Thank you for your help.